# IPAddress.TryParse returning undesired result

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a function that returns if a given ip address is valid or not using the IPAddress class. I was testing it and it returns valid(true) even when I pass "0123456" or "11111" or "99999" without a dot as argument. I wrote it in VB.net and C# with the same result.

```
// C#
public bool CheckIpAddress(string ipAddr)
{
    IPAddress ip = null;
    return IPAddress.TryParse(ipAddr,out ip);
}

  // VB.net
  Public Function CheckIpAddress(ipAddr As String) As Boolean
        Dim ip As IPAddress = Nothing

        Return Net.IPAddress.TryParse(ipAddr, ip)
    End Function
```

Could somebody explain me why is this happening. I have matched my code with some sources through the internet and is fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IP Address is just 32 bit number, so `11111` is definitely a correct IP Address. Dots in IP Address are there just to make reading them easier for humans. They are not required.

> **IP addresses are binary numbers**, but they are **usually** stored in text files and displayed in human-readable notations, such as 172.16.254.1 (for IPv4), and 2001:db8:0:1234:0:567:8:1 (for IPv6).
>
> from [IP address - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address)

That's why `IPAddress.TryParse` returns `true`.

It's even described on MSDN: [`IPAddress.Parse` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The number of parts (each part is separated by a period) in ipString determines how the IP address is constructed. **A one part address is stored directly in the network address**. A two part address, convenient for specifying a class A address, puts the leading part in the first byte and the trailing part in the right-most three bytes of the network address. A three part address, convenient for specifying a class B address, puts the first part in the first byte, the second part in the second byte, and the final part in the right-most two bytes of the network address.

There is also an example (see the first one):

```
1 -- "65536"       0.0.255.255
2 -- "20.2"        20.0.0.2
2 -- "20.65535"    20.0.255.255
3 -- "128.1.2"     128.1.0.2
```

Comment: I know how an ip address is compound, the right format and so on. 11111 is not a valid ip address, 1.1.1.1 is valid. So what you're telling me is that this method (tryParse) only check every 8 bits parts? Why returns true with 999?

Comment: `11111` is a valid IP address, because it fits into 32bits number. Dots within an IP address are there just to make reading addresses easier for humans. But it doesn't mean they are required. From wiki: *IP addresses are **binary numbers**, but they are **usually** stored in text files and displayed in **human-readable notations**, such as 172.16.254.1 (for IPv4), and 2001:db8:0:1234:0:567:8:1 (for IPv6).*

Comment: so there's any other class that can check a readable ip address format?

Comment: I don't know any. But you should be able to write such functionality by yourself quite easily.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to validate against a pattern, you should instead be using a RegEx.
This code should help:

```
 Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$");
 if (match.Success)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("It is a valid IP Address");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this had a vb.net tag

```
Public Function CheckIpAddress(ipAddr As String) As Boolean
    Dim parts() As String = ipAddr.Split(New Char() {"."c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim rv As Boolean
    If parts.Length <> 4 Then
        rv = False
    Else
        Dim anIP As Net.IPAddress
        If Net.IPAddress.TryParse(ipAddr, anIP) Then
            rv = True
        Else
            rv = False
        End If
    End If
    Return rv
End Function
```